# Error on query by sum and fetch row - sql

Tags: mysql, sql

i have error on my sql query.

my query :

```
SELECT sum(billsItems_Quantity) as TotalQ , 
    sum(billsItems_ItemDiscount) as TotalD , 
    sum(billsItems_ItemTotal) as TotalI , 
    bills.bills_ID , 
    billsitems.billsItems_BillItemSerial , 
    bills.bills_CashierID , 
    bills.bills_StoreID , 
    billsitems.billsItems_Unit , 
    billsitems.billsItems_Price 
FROM bills , billsitems 
WHERE bills.bills_ID = billsitems.billsItems_BillItemSerial
  and bills.bills_CashierID = '".$id."'
  and bills.bills_StoreID = '$ausers_StoreId'
order by billsitems.billsItems_Unit
```

In my query I need to get sum of `billsItems_Quantity` , `billsItems_ItemDiscount` `billsItems_ItemTotal` by use sum function , in the same query I need to get all item of the table.

the error :

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in
```

Comment: What SQL database?  What error?  (Probably the problem is you need a `group by` clause to use `sum`).

Comment: What is the error that you are getting?

Comment: `Warning: mysql_fetch_array(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in`

Comment: plz add the error to the question (you can update the question), its easier for ppl to find it there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I think I understand your problem. Are you usign SQL Server 2005 or newer?

If so, you can do this with the "OVER" clause, wich will let you do sums and get all the other columns. here's a way to do this

```
SELECT sum(billsItems_Quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY /*group by columns for the sum here*/) as TotalQ , 
   sum (billsItems_ItemDiscount) OVER (PARTITION BY /*group by columns for the sum here*/) as TotalD , 
   sum (billsItems_ItemTotal) OVER (PARTITION BY /*group by columns for the sum here*/) as TotalI , 
   bills.bills_ID , billsitems.billsItems_BillItemSerial , bills.bills_CashierID , 
   bills.bills_StoreID , billsitems.billsItems_Unit , billsitems.billsItems_Price FROM bills , 
   billsitems 
WHERE bills.bills_ID = billsitems.billsItems_BillItemSerial
  and bills.bills_CashierID = '".$id."'
  and bills.bills_StoreID = '$ausers_StoreId'
order by billsitems.billsItems_Unit
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is because you did not add GROUP BY, try

```
    SELECT sum(billsItems_Quantity) as TotalQ , 
        sum(billsItems_ItemDiscount) as TotalD , 
        sum(billsItems_ItemTotal) as TotalI , 
        bills.bills_ID , 
        billsitems.billsItems_BillItemSerial , 
        bills.bills_CashierID , 
        bills.bills_StoreID , 
        billsitems.billsItems_Unit , 
        billsitems.billsItems_Price 
    FROM bills , billsitems 
    WHERE bills.bills_ID = billsitems.billsItems_BillItemSerial
      and bills.bills_CashierID = '".$id."'
      and bills.bills_StoreID = '$ausers_StoreId'

    GROUP BY bills.bills_ID , 
        billsitems.billsItems_BillItemSerial , 
        bills.bills_CashierID , 
        bills.bills_StoreID , 
        billsitems.billsItems_Unit , 
        billsitems.billsItems_Price

    ORDER BY billsitems.billsItems_Unit
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided a lot of details, but you might be able to use a subquery for the `sum()` and then join back to your table:

```
SELECT i1.TotalQ , 
    i1.TotalD , 
    i1.TotalI , 
    b.bills_ID , 
    i2.billsItems_BillItemSerial , 
    b.bills_CashierID , 
    b.bills_StoreID , 
    i2.billsItems_Unit , 
    i2.billsItems_Price 
FROM bills b
INNER JOIN
(
    select sum(billsItems_Quantity) TotalQ,
        sum(billsItems_ItemDiscount) as TotalD,
        sum(billsItems_ItemTotal) as TotalI,
        billsItems_BillItemSerial
    from  billsitems
    group by billsItems_BillItemSerial
)  i1
    ON b.bills_ID = i1.billsItems_BillItemSerial
inner join billsitems i2
    on b.bills_ID = i2.billsItems_BillItemSerial
WHERE b.bills_CashierID = '".$id."'
  and b.bills_StoreID = '$ausers_StoreId'
order by i2.billsItems_Unit
```

Comment: thank but i canot get value of  sum(billsItems_ItemTotal) how can i print it on php